# How to add column in orders Excel xml export?

Tags: xml, sales, export

In magento backend it is possible to export the list of the orders in Excel XML format.

I would like to add columns in this file such as the company name (present in the customer address) and the payment method but I do not find the function exporting the datas...

Thank you for your help,

Answer (score 0):

The export is based upon the grid you are rendering so if you want to add additional columns you need to add them to the grid. If you don't want to show them you need to do some custom code that hides them for specific conditions or change the grid your are exporting.

With orders however you need to note that the data is not all stored in order grid table since it only stores data used in the default grid.

So you either need to change the collection model used in Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid method: _getCollectionClass

```
class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid
```

And the method

```
protected function _getCollectionClass()
```

To fit what you need. Or you can add the fields to the grid table and then make magento move them there via the config.xml (See the Sales moduls config.xml)

Comment: I managed to add the columns I needed on the grid, but the export does not include them...